# Sequelize ORM - Include two relationships as a single parent property

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a schema with three models: a **School**, a **Teacher**, and a **Student**.
A school can have multiple teachers and multiple students.

I can get a list of `schools` with Sequelize like this:

```
return School.findAll({
    include: [
        { model: Teacher },
        { model: Student },
    ],
});
```

Which results in JSON like this:

```
[{
    id: 'dc85fe6a-c009-4055-9852-e2c3c0b37e9b,
    teachers: [ ... ],
    students: [ ... ]
}]
```

Now, I want that JSON to also include a property called `people` that includes the session's `teachers` and `students`.
In other words, the JSON should look like this:

```
[{
    id: 'dc85fe6a-c009-4055-9852-e2c3c0b37e9b,
    people: [ ... ], // Should contain teachers and students.
    teachers: [ ... ],
    students: [ ... ]
}]
```

How can I "include" multiple relationships into a single property like this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that using sequelize. However, your usecase would typically work better using an inheritance pattern. Think about it, what do Students and Teacher have in common? They're both human beings, so any attribute that a human being has is common to both.

Here is what I would do:

- Have a model called `Person`, containing all the common properties (first name, last name, birth date...)
- Have two other models, `Student` and `Teacher`, containing specific properties
- Define `one to one` relationships between `Student`/`Teacher` and `Person`. Be careful, you can only define it one way (a `Student` is a `Person` but a `Person` isn't always a `Student`)
- Define a `one to many` relationship from `School` to `Person`.

That way, you would be able to achieve what you want by doing the following:

```
return School.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Person,
            include: [
                { model: Teacher },
                { model: Student },
            ]
        },
    ],
});
```

And, imho, I believe this model would be more fitting regarding normalization.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would this work even if the Person model had no defined properties (other than necessary keys)? I ask because usually I run into similar problems when I've used the `Marker interface pattern`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern. So going back to the original example, say that I know for a fact that I never want the Student model and Teacher model to have common properties. Would this still be the best way to go?

Comment: I did not try, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work with just the id.